# Remap value of range input element

Tags: javascript

I have following input range (slider), values allowed are from 0 to 100.
I need to map values from the slider to a input text, with the following rules:

```
      range => text
          0 => 2000
        100 =>  200
```

With the value in between accordingly.
Currently I am using the following script, which works, but I would like to know if there is a better way to do it.

```js
var slider = document.querySelector('#slider');
var result = document.querySelector('#result');
slider.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var sliderValue = event.target.value;
  var maxValue = 2000;
  var coef = 18;
  var calc;
  calc = maxValue - (sliderValue * coef);
  result.value = calc;
});
```

```html
<input id="slider" type="range" name="points" min="0" max="100" value=0>
<input id="result" type="text" name="result">
```

Comment: This seems like more of a question for StackOverflow?

Comment: @Randyr they just told me to write it here on Code Review :)

Comment: Yea, now that I re-read the question I can see why. I first thought it _wasn't_ working, but it is. Hence the reference to stackoverflow. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: **1.** Wrap code in IIFE to avoid globals **2.** Move constants out of event handler **3.** `this` in handler refer to the element on which the event has occurred **4.** Remove variables that are used once. [Here is the demo of these suggestions](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vu7qzyts/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would move out that equation to its own function. It takes an input number (your value), and returns a result (the text). Doing it this way makes easily testable functions a habit.

```
function getTextFromRangeValue(value){
  return maxValue - (value * coef);
}
```

With this comes separation of your DOM handler logic. This allows your logic (the calculation code) to be very reusable as it is now detached from the DOM-handling code.

```
slider.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  result.value = getTextFromRangeValue(event.target.value);
});
```

`maxValue` and `coef` are constants, fixed values. It's a programming convention to name constants with uppercase characters separated with underscores. Additionally, lift them out the handler scope so they're not recreated on every call. They should be named in full, avoid abbreviations.

```
var slider = document.querySelector('#slider');
var result = document.querySelector('#result');
var MAX_VALUE = 2000;
var COEFFICIENT = 18;
```

If I were to rewrite this code, here's how I'd do it.

```
const slider = document.querySelector('#slider');
const result = document.querySelector('#result');
const MAXIMUM_VALUE = 2000;
const COEFFICIENT = 18;

function getTextFromRangeValue(value){
  return MAXIMUM_VALUE - (value * COEFFICIENT);
}

slider.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  result.value = getTextFromRangeValue(event.target.value);
});
```

Lastly, as mentioned in the comments, if this code isn't in a module or in its own scope, consider wrapping in an IIFE to avoid cloberring and being clobbered in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

### Selecting elements by ID

When obtaining a reference to an element by its ID, it's more efficient to use `document.getElementById` than `document.querySelector`.

Instead of:

```
var slider = document.querySelector('#slider');
```

You can use:

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
```

### Avoiding polluting the global namespace

As pointed out in a comment, you can wrap the code in an immediately executing function expression (IIFE) to avoid polluting the global namespace.

Variables declared within the scope of a function expression can only be accessed from within the expression and from functions that are also defined within the expression.

```
(function(){
    // your code here
})();
```

### Using the 'const' modern language feature

If you don't need to support older versions of Internet Explorer, you can take advantage of the `const` keyword (introduced in ECMAScript 2015) for any variable whose value never changes. This not only makes it easier for you to detect any inadvertent logic errors introduced by overwriting those variable values, but it allows the browser's JavaScript engine to optimize its handling of those variables since it knows they'll never change.

Your `maxValue` and `coef` variables could be defined as constants at the beginning of your IIFE, as could your references to HTML elements.

```
(function(){
    const COEF = 18, MAX_VALUE = 2000, RESULT_TEXTBOX = document.getElementById('result');
    // your code here
})();
```

Some variable naming conventions use ALL_CAPS for constants, which I've shown in the code above, but internal consistency is more important than external convention.

### Eliminating unnecessary variables

You are only using the `slider` variable once, for the one-time assignment of the event handler. You can therefore bypass storing it in a variable altogether and just directly assign the event handler to the reference returned by `document.getElementById`.

Similarly, `sliderValue` and `calc` are each used only once after being defined in the event handler; you can eliminate them altogether. (`sliderValue` can be replaced with `event.target.value` or `this.value`.)

```
(function(){
    const COEF = 18, 
      MAX_VALUE = 2000, 
      RESULT_TEXTBOX = document.getElementById('result');
    document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('change',function(){
        RESULT_TEXTBOX.value = MAX_VALUE - (this.value * COEF);
    });
})();
```

Note that you'd have good reason to reinstate the extra intermediary variables if any of them were being used more than once.

Note also that I'm not suggesting that you eliminate the `maxValue` and `coef` variables and replace them with their literal numerical values, even though they're each only used once. In their case the intermediary constants serve to eliminate "magic numbers" and make the code easier to maintain.

You could similarly endeavor to eliminate "magic strings" and convert your element IDs into constants.